# Injected DLL does nothing

Tags: c++, dll, dll-injection

I attempted to inject a C++ DLL in another WIN32 console programme. The injector (winjet) shows that it is successfully injected but the DLL itself does nothing.
As compiler I use Visual Studio 2013 and I just found out if I use precompiled header and this preset .cpp instead of a empty project without precompiled header, it works.

Dll.cpp :

```
BOOL APIENTRY Dllmain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved){
     switch (reason) {
     case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
          MessageBoxA(NULL, "Attached!", "InjectedDLL", MB_OK);
     }
     return TRUE;
}
```

This code works with preset settings and precompiled header. But why it doesn't without that?

Comment: Beep has restrictions where it is possible. Depending on the target process, it might inject properly, but without Beep. Other than that, your question has to little information to help.

Comment: @deviantfan There was a mistake in the code given, so it was enough information. But cheers for downvoting my question doe :P

Comment: a) There were "two" downvoters (and one upvote from a third person). b) Don´t go around blaming people for things without knowing if they had done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point to a Windows DLL is called `DllMain`, not `Dllmain`.

You do not get a compile error for this (like when mis-spelling `main`), because it is optional.